# Memory Leak on Ejabberd 17.12

Tags: ejabberd

We're running **ejabberd 17.12** server for simple MUC chat over BOSH.
We use the REST API to create MUC non-persistent rooms at runtime as well as to manage users.

**Enabled modules :**  `mod_adhoc, mod_admin_extra, mod_announce, mod_blocking, mod_bosh, mod_caps, mod_carboncopy, mod_client_state, mod_configure, mod_disco, mod_http_api, mod_last, mod_mam, mod_muc, mod_muc_admin, mod_muc_log, mod_offline, mod_ping, mod_privacy, mod_private, mod_pubsub, mod_push, mod_push_keepalive, mod_roster, mod_s2s_dialback, mod_stream_mgmt, mod_vcard, mod_vcard_xupdate, mod_version`.

We're facing a memory leak where erlang always reports nearly 50mb usage but the OS memory allocation always keep on increasing. Eventually it crashes in 2-3 days.
The error log reports amnesia overloaded & SQL timeout but after cross-checking the DB server (RDS) it didn't have any crashes or unavailability in it's logs.
You can check the error logs [here](https://pastebin.com/UXDrRHYb)

I have checked other posts & tried the suggestions but to no avail. I've removed mod_shared_roster as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue (leak in the TLS driver) and is fixed in 18.01+.

Comment: I'll upgrade the installation to 18.04 & will let you know.

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is resolved after upgrading to 18.01.